# Group by in hive with CASE

Tags: group-by, hive, case

Is there any way to get the expected output in hive using query?

```
select (CASE WHEN visit=1 THEN 'ONE' WHEN visit=2 THEN 'TWO' ELSE 'ABOVE_TWO' END),
count(visit) from sample_tbl 
group by (CASE WHEN visit=1 THEN 'ONE' WHEN visit=2 THEN 'TWO' ELSE 'ABOVE_TWO' END);
```

### sample_tbl

> visit
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 3
>
> 3

### output

> ONE 2
>
> ABOVE_TWO 2

### Expected

> ONE 2
>
> TWO 0
>
> ABOVE_TWO 2

Answer (score 0):

I am not a hive expert, but you can try:

```
select
   CASE WHEN visit=1 
           THEN 'ONE' 
        WHEN visit=2 
           THEN 'TWO'
        ELSE 'ABOVE_TWO' 
   END as visit,
   cnt
from
(
    select visit, count(*) as cnt
    from sample_tbl
    group by visit
)s
```

Answer (score 0):

`select case visit when 1 then 'ONE' when 2 then 'TWO' else 'ABOVE_TWO' end as visit,count(visit) from sample_tbl GROUP BY visit;`

Comment: There are customer table available and visit column contains the customer's number of visit to the store. We need to pull the data as how many times the customer has visited to the store and need to draw Bar graph. So when we are pulling the data, if no data is available for the specific scenario(contains in switch case of the query) it should show as '0'.  We can handle this through the code. But I need the solution to handle this through query.